# Consistent spacing in the Dragon Ball-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have [dragonball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-gt) and [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball), the latter of which has a space between "dragon" and "ball". As far as I know, in English, the names of these shows are "Dragon Ball GT" and "Dragon Ball", so it seems like we should change [dragonball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-gt) → [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt).

(Is this an utterly trivial matter? Yes. Am I a pedant? Also yes.)

Comment: Yes plz [dragon-ball-gt].